# Adding Image from Filesystem to Jlabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I working on a project, where i need to display images in a JFrame. The images are downloaded dynamically and need to be stored outside the jar file. How do i display images (using Jlabel)  from the computer's file-system ?

Comment: how will user know the path of image , will it be asked from user through file selector dialog

Comment: images are to be stored in a known folder, after downloading the images the java program is supposed to load the image and display it.

Comment: so the path is known to program or arbitary ?? is it known that the image will be downloaded at "c:\\image" or other folder

Comment: The path is known to the program and is stored in a string variable. It should be of this form - "C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\allfiles"
The image is downloaded in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the images are stored in a folder say 'image' or whatever location. I am supposing that you have an image folder inside src (source folder), though you may change it to whatever location you want.

```
/*
URL logoUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/images/login_icon.png"); // you can change this location
Toolkit tk1 = this.getToolkit();   
logo = tk1.getImage(logoUrl);
*/
// use above code if the image lies within your jar file
// otherwise use below code for images stored in path like C:\User\Desktop ..

ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Desert.jpg");    
jLabel2.setIcon(image);  // where jLabel2 is your label
```

This will work!

Comment: I have edited my code after seeing your comments. If you want to use images inside your 'src' folder, you use previous code. Otherwise for images stored outside in locations like C:\Users\MyPics\image1.jpg, you use the updated 2 lines code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class ShowPic extends JFrame{
    private JLabel lblDisplay = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("im.jpg"));
    public ShowPic()
    {
        JPanel pan1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(450,450));
        pan1.add(lblDisplay , BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(pan1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new ShowPic();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

If you having images in a known folder then you can get the images like this

```
List<String> filename=new ArrayList<String>();
File aFile = new File("C:\\image");
if(aFile.isDirectory())
{
          filename=Arrays.asList(aFile.listFiles());
}

List<JLabel> lb=new ArrayList<JLabel>();
for(int i=0;i<filename.size();i++)
{

    lblDisplay = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("c:\\image"+filename.get(i)));

   lb.add(lblDisplay);

}
```

lb is Arraylist f objects of JLabel each having per file reference in the directory.